# How to retrieve data from a ListControl(ListView)?

Tags: c, windows, mfc

I have a listcontrol with three columns. I want to read what text is in the third column. I need this, because i want color this column according to that what text is in it. Can anyone tell me, how to read the data?

Thanks in advance!

kampi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your control's associated CListCtrl is called m_listCtrl simply use:

```
CString colText = m_listCtrl.GetItemText(item, subitem);
```

You associate that variable with the control itself via something like this:

```
void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listCtrl);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! It's working fine! But now i have an other problem. Hope you can answer this too. If i want to use SetTextColor then it pastes my text with the color i want, but if i click on a row, or scroll it down then it will color the full row, and eventually everything will be colored. How can i color only the third column(according what text is in it)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @kampi: Please post this as a new question since it is not related to the original asked question and subject.

Comment: Hi! I already did post this as a new question but i didn't get a usefull answer :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282621/how-to-insert-colored-text-int-a-listview

Comment: Thanks I was going to answer it but someone beat me to it.  You have to do the painting yourself.  Unfortunately there is no very easy solution.   Edit: I posted an answer though anyway with an already implemented class that I think does that.